# How to make a 2D List with the logic of 2D Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I have the **array[100,10]** and i wanna transfer it to a **list**(for example List<List> arrayToList = new List<List>();)
By logic of array i mean that when i print the list(Console.WriteLine(arrayToList)) i want it to be in the logic as bellow:

[Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3//first row

Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3//second row

etc....
Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3]//100th row

Also i want it to be saved the same way in the List. For example i want the arrayToList[10,8] to return the column 8 and row 10 with the value of the array[10,8]. First of all, is it possible? And if it is, how its done? And if its not, is there any other way to do it that way or something close to it?

Tnx in advance!!!

```
public class TransferToList1 : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<List<Vector3>> arrayToList = new List<List<Vector3>>();
public Vector3[,] array = new Vector3[100, 10];
private void Start()
{
        //------ building array ------
        // Starting the transfer to arrayToList
        for (int i = 0; i < size0 /*size0 = array.GetLength(0)*/; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size1 /*size1 = array.GetLength(1)*/; j++)
            {
                arrayToList[i].Add(array[i, j]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size0; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 0 ] = " + arrayToList[i][0]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 1 ] = " + arrayToList[i][1]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 2 ] = " + arrayToList[i][2]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 3 ] = " + arrayToList[i][3]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 4 ] = " + arrayToList[i][4]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 5 ] = " + arrayToList[i][5]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 6 ] = " + arrayToList[i][6]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 7 ] = " + arrayToList[i][7]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 8 ] = " + arrayToList[i][8]);
            Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + ", 9 ] = " + arrayToList[i][9]);
        }
}

/* With the above im getting this error:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at <3dd5df5ef4974f29afeb2d3ba227c5da>:0)
*/
}
```

Comment: Possible? Yes. Possible without writing a bunch of manual utility code to handle the translations and conversions and replicating the behavior? Unlikely. For the specific error  you are getting in the loops, though, instead of using `array.GetLength(0)` and `array.getLength(1)`, you will need to do `array.Length` and `array[i].Length`, respectively.

Comment: Also, any particular reason you want to move away from using a 2D array to using an array-or-arrays but still want to treat it as a 2D array? Why not just stick with using a 2D array?

Comment: You'll need to subclass `List<List<T>>` and override ToString with your own implementation. However if possible, it'll be nicer to implement something like a `ToStringAs2dArray` static function somewhere instead, maybe even as an extension method. Then call it manually to convert your list to a string.

Comment: @Abion47 The reason i want to change to a list is because i need to delete rows as i will process but that will happen after i figure this out.  Also `array.Length` and `array[i].Length` didn't work for me. Still thanks for answering!!

Comment: @Verpous So i can understand. Do i have to make a (as you said) ToStringAs2dArray function that does the conversion of list to string for printing out?

Comment: @zarzanefye Why does it matter if you're using `[][]` vs `[,]` if you're going through the trouble of converting them to `List<List<>>` anyway?

Comment: @Abion47 The reason is that i can understand it better like that [,] and also the creation of `array[100,10]` has already be done like that(mostly fill the array).

Comment: @zarzanefye Yes that is exactly what I mean. You're going to have to implement such a function either way, what I'm suggesting is to make it a static function, maybe an extension method, rather than to implement an entire class with this function as its ToString.

Comment: OK, I see my confusion. In that case, yeah, what Verpous said. I'd also recommend that you just bite the bullet and fully commit to using `List<List<>>` without having a `[,]` as a pointless buffer. In your attempt to remain in your comfort zone, you are just going to give yourself more work and complexity for no reason.

Comment: @Verpous I'll try that and if it works i'll post the final result(hopefully working). Also any suggestion about the error i am getting? Thanks for your opinion on the matter!!!

Comment: Abion47 and Verpous thanks for you fast answers on the matter! I'll start building the conversion function and i'll see if it works. Thanks again for your time!!